# Cakephp: Designpattern for creation of models in hasMany relationship

Tags: cakephp

I have two Models: Car and Passenger.

> Car hasMany Passenger
>
> Passenger belongsTo Car

I managed to create add functionality for each model and managed to resolve the hasMany relationship between them.

Now I'm trying to create a addCar function and view that allows the user to create a new car and automatically generate Passengers.

I thought of something like this

- The view asks the user enter the car information
- The view has some field that allows to temporarily add new passengers and remove remove them
- When the user saves the new car, the entities for the passengers are created, the entity for the car is created and the passengers are linked to the car.
- If the user decides to cancel everything, the DB remains unchanged.

Now my question is: What is the best way to do this? Is there a pattern / tutorial to follow for such a entity and associated subentity creation?

To clarify: The passengers associated with each car do not exist prior to the existence of the car.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the following code in the view **views/passengers/add_cars.ctp**:

```
<?php
echo $this->Form->create('Car');
echo $this->Form->input('name');
echo $this->Form->input('model');
echo $this->Form->input('Passenger.0.name');
echo $this->Form->input('Passenger.0.age');
echo $this->Form->input('Passenger.1.name');
echo $this->Form->input('Passenger.1.age');
echo $this->Form->end();
?>
```

This basically starts off with the necessary fields to input the car information. Then, you can start a loop with a general format of `Passenger.{$i}.name` to add passengers dynamically when a new car is added. You can use jQuery to create "add" and "remove" buttons that will add or remove rows of Passenger form entries.

In your **passengers_controller.php** (assuming this is the controller you want add_cars), use the `saveAll` function:

```
function add_cars() {
    if (!empty($this->data)) {
        if ($this->Passenger->Car->saveAll($this->data)) {
            $this->Session->setFlash('Success');
            $this->redirect('/');
        } else {
            $this->Session->setFlash('Error');
        }
    }
}
```

Hope that helps.